# Maven Artiface Relocated on One Computer, but not on Another

Tags: maven

I tried "mvn install" to build a project. The project can be built successfully on one virtual machine, but failed to build on another virtual machine.

The warning message for failed build:

```
[WARNING] The artifact com.lowagie:itext:jar:4.2.1 has been relocated to com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.6
```

Configurations of VMs:
Virtual Machine 1 (successfully built)

```
$ uname -a 
Linux river 3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 5 16:07:00 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 
$ java -version java
version "1.7.0_91" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.2.3.el7-x86_64 u91-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode) 
$ mvn -v 
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (NON-CANONICAL_2015-03-04T12:12:39_root; 2015-03-04T12:12:39-06:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven 
Java version: 1.7.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation 
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91-2.6.2.3.el7.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Virtual Machine 2 (failed to build)

```
$ uname -a
Linux ams 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 9 14:09:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.4.0.el7_2-x86_64 u95-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T11:29:23-06:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.7.0_95, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95-2.6.4.0.el7_2.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Could be that one of the machine has the artifact cached locally. Remove ~/.m2/repository/com/lowagie/itext on the machine that worked, it should cease working. Then change your pom.xml to reference the artifact at its new location. Consider using artifact repository proxy like Nexus or Artifactory.

Comment: I changed the original configuration to
                        <groupId>com.itexpdf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
                        <version>5.5.6</version>
                </dependency>
. But then received this error: Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/itexpdf/itextpdf/5.5.6/itextpdf-5.5.6.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.itexpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.6 is missing, no dependency information available

Comment: I corrected the type (itexpdf) in the groupId. Now the error is GeneratePdfView is not abstract and does not override abstract method buildPdfDocument(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>,com.lowagie.text.Document,com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) in org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractPdfView. Why the error still mentioned lowagie?

Comment: It seems that the abstractPdfView deprecated since it's api still uses lowagi.